# AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter : exclude mock files from webpack config for PROD builds

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I'm using the [AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) and I've been struggling with its `webpack` configuration for a while, although what I want to achieve seems very simple.

Basically, I have some *mock* files located in `src\assets\mock\data` that I'd like to keep in the **dev** build, but that I want to exclude from the **prod** build. These *mock* files should be excluded from the **prod** build according to a regexp on their name (I tried several flavours of something like `exclude: [/^mock\.data\..*\.json$/]`, or by folder, or at the very least by listing them all.

The **dev** build using [webpack.dev.js](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.dev.js) is fine, but I've been tinkering with the [webpack.prod.js](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.prod.js) file to no avail until now.

Could someone point me in the right direction ? Thank you.

Comment: what are the extensions of these mock files?

Comment: `.json`. Does it matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context: *angular2-webpack-starter*

The assets folder recopy during the build task is handle by a webpack plugin aka [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin). By default it is only setup in the *webpack.common.js*.
To achieve what you are trying to, you should put the same task in both of your environments. That way you would be able to exclude the unwanted files.

1. webpack.common.js

   ```
   new CopyWebpackPlugin([
     { from: 'src/meta'}
   ])
   ```
2. webpack.dev.js

   ```
   new CopyWebpackPlugin([
     { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' }
   ])
   ```
3. webpack.prod.js

   ```
   new CopyWebpackPlugin([
     { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets', ignore: ['mock/data/*'] }
   ])
   ```