# Angular + webpack + require.context: Avoid including mock-data within main bundle

Tags: angular, webpack, build, mocking, production

I use webpack to bundle a Angular application.

In my main module, I import providers from an other file:

```
import { ENV_PROVIDERS } from './environment';
```

In environment.ts, I have the following code:

```
/**
 * Environment Providers
 */
let PROVIDERS: any[] = [];

if ( 'production' === ENV ) {

  PROVIDERS = [
    ...PROVIDERS,
    /**
     * Custom providers in production.
     */
  ];

} else {

  PROVIDERS = [
    ...PROVIDERS,
    /**
     * Custom providers in development.
     */
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MockHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ];

}

export const ENV_PROVIDERS = [
  ...PROVIDERS,
];
```

The result is that on Production, I don't have the MockHttpInterceptor and I  target my back-end correctly. This works perfectly fine.

The problem I am facing is that when I do my production build, my main bundle file size is big. I noticed it includes all the mock-data in there.

My guess is that webpack goes trough `environment.ts` during build, ignore the check `( production === ENV )`, and when webpack goes through MockHttpInterceptor, he includes all the mock-data files that I include using `require.context`.

My question is: **How do I avoid this behaviour ?**

If I comment my custom dev provider before doing a PROD build:

```
  PROVIDERS = [
    ...PROVIDERS,
    /**
     * Custom providers in development.
     */
    // {
    //   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    //   useClass: MockHttpInterceptor,
    //   multi: true,
    // },
  ];
```

The bundle size reduces a lot because all the mock files are not included.

Comment: I think this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612735/angularclass-angular2-webpack-starter-exclude-mock-files-from-webpack-config-f

Comment: @Gourishankar I played with that and I have actually the same code in my webpack config, the mock-data are not copied as such but they are included in my main bundle (called main.a3178e4cdcf2e634a55e.chunk.js). I don't want them included in the bundle because in PROD they are not used.